# Using R package RJulia

Tags: r, julia

I would like to install the R Package JuliaCall, to use Julia from R. I have installed Julia via snap and installed the JuliaCall R package form the Cran.
I received the following error when trying to use the setup function of JuliaCall.

```r
library(JuliaCall)
julia <- julia_setup()
```

> Julia version 1.0.4 at location /snap/julia/13/bin will be used.
>   Error in dyn.load(.julia$dll_file) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/snap/julia/13/bin/../lib/libjulia.so.1':
>     /snap/julia/13/bin/../lib/libjulia.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
>    Show Traceback
>
> Rerun with Debug
>    Error in juliacall_initialize(.julia$dll_file) : 
>     /snap/julia/13/bin/../lib/libjulia.so.1 - /snap/julia/13/bin/../lib/libjulia.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Julia is installed:

```r
 XRJulia::findJulia()
```

[1] "/snap/bin/julia"

I have tried some suggestions found in 
https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues/72
and even report my problems, but I'm not sure if this is an issue to open on Github or a problem with my installation. 
The same error occurs

My system specifications are:

- Ubuntu 18.04,
- Rstudio 1.1.456,
- R 3.5.1,
- Julia installed via snap

Thanks for any help you could provide

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the developer of JuliaCall answered my question.
I have installed Julia using snap without noticing that a 32bits version was used. Installing Julia from the .tar.gz archive and choosing the correct 64 bits version solve this problem. 
Many Thanks to @Non-Contradiction.